# Very simple Q about constructors with an array object

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I wrote a class called `MenuItem` which includes:

```
private String name;
private String description;
private double price;

public MenuItem(String name, String description, double price)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
}
```

as well as accessor and mutator methods for all the variables, and another class called `Menu` which includes the constructor:

```
public Menu()
{
    menu = new MenuItem[50];
}
```

In my main method, I wrote:

```
Menu menu = new Menu();
```

in an attempt to create a `Menu` array called menu with 50 `MenuItem` objects inside. However I know I did something wrong because when I try to refer to one of the objects in the array i.e.

```
System.out.print("The name of this item is " + menu[1].getName());
```

I get a compiling error that points to the menu[1] and says **array required, but Menu found.**

How do I fix this?

Comment: where do you have this System.out.println? is it in Menu class?

Comment: The System.out.print is in the main method of another class, MenuOperations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the reason you're confused is because you have 3 different 'menus' inside your program right now. You have `Menu`, the class. You have **menu**, the array, which is inside the any instance of the `Menu` class. And finally, you have *menu* the object, which you created inside your main method.

In your main method, when you do *menu*[1], you're telling Java "take *menu*, the object, and try and get the first indice of it". However, since the *menu* inside main isn't an array, Java will not know what to do and will refuse to compile.

Instead, you want to find **menu**, the array, inside *menu*, the object, and get the indice of that:

```
 System.out.print("The name is: " + menu.menu[1].getName());
```

So, to sum up, you have an instance of the `Menu` class called *menu* which contains an array named **menu**!

I suppose the main takeaway here is to always make sure to use clear and unambiguous variable names to avoid confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables calles `menu`. This is ok as they are in separate scopes (one is in the `main`, one a member of your `class Menu`), but maybe that's where the confusion comes from. In the class `Menu`, it is an array, but in your `main` method, it is a simple variable. So if you want to print out the second element in the array (which is `menu[1]`), you must do that in your `Menu` class somewhere. (Or create a getter to access it from the `main` method).